# Java applet, add jar files to the manifest file

Tags: java, ant, applet

I am doing some thing obvious wrong. I have a simple applet which needs to upload files to server. I have written an ant script to build the jar file. However, the manifest.mf has class-path split into multiple lines.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Class-Path: lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar            lib/commons-httpclien
 t-3.1.jar            lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar            lib/plu
 gin.jar
Created-By: 14.3-b01-101 (Apple Inc.)
```

My build.xml is :

```
<project name="ScreenShot" default="dist" basedir=".">
 <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
 <!-- set global properties for this build -->
 <property name="src" location="src" />
 <property name="build" location="build" />
 <property name="dist" location="dist" />

 <target name="init">
  <!-- Create the time stamp -->
  <tstamp />
  <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
  <mkdir dir="${build}" />
 </target>

 <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">


  <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
  <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
   <classpath>
    <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
    <pathelement path="lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar:lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:lib/plugin.jar" />
   </classpath>

  </javac>
 </target>

 <target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
  <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
  <mkdir dir="${dist}" />


  <copy todir="${build}/lib">
   <fileset dir="lib/" />
  </copy>

  <path id="libs.project">

   <!-- lib.home contains all jar files, in several subdirectories -->
   <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar" />
   </fileset>
  </path>

  <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" maxParentLevels="1" jarfile="build/ScreenShot.jar">

   <classpath refid="libs.project" />
  </manifestclasspath>

  <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
  <jar jarfile="/Users/firemonk/red5/webapps/whiteboard/ScreenShot.jar" basedir="${build}">
   <manifest>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
   </manifest>
  </jar>
 </target>



 <target name="clean" description="clean up">
  <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
  <delete dir="${build}" />
  <delete dir="${dist}" />
 </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `${jar.classpath}`. It seems its value itself is in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Does it not work?  It's a bit odd that there are big spaces between each classpath entry but it looks valid.

The [manifest specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Manifest%20Specification) states that lines must be no longer than 72 bytes and that longer lines should be split and continued on the next line with a leading space.

Comment: I have created a test project and with a simple class(MyTest) and 4 jar files in the lib folder. MyTest is instantiating a class from each jar file to access all the jar files. 

I am trying to have my build file create the jar. 

finally I using this command to test :
java -cp ScreenShot.jar org.test.Delme


I always get class not found error

Comment: The link to download the simple project is : 

http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B23I0Lzc_6noNTVmMDhmZDMtMDZlYi00ZmU4LWJkOTYtMDhkNzUyNmQxZGQ5&hl=en

Comment: Can you please make the simple jar file work. I can't see what am I missing. I have spent 2 days on this.